# What did Larry David say to Cheryl when they met in a fundraiser in Curb Your Enthusiasm

Tags: dialogue, curb-your-enthusiasm

I recall a scene where Larry David meets Cheryl in a Fundraiser (Season 9 Episode 1) after their breakup or divorce and the fundraiser is called **People Against Mutilation** and he cracks a hilarious joke about vaginas or mutilation in general.

I am looking for the dialog itself.

Is there a website where I can read the dialogue for the scene?

Comment: This isn't an identification question. It is asking about a specific dialogue from a transcript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

> What is this name, PAM? That's the best you could do? It's like-- it's a cooking spray-- PAM.
>
> No, it's People Against Mutilation, genital mutilation.
>
> Yeah, I know what it stands for.
>
> And there are very few charities that actually focus on the clitoris and talk about it.
>
> I think you got half the population focused on the clitoris.
>
> I'm deadly focused on it.
>
> <sup>Read more: https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=curb-your-enthusiasm&episode=s09e01</sup>